# Why doesn't ajaxModalExtender hide ?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have used AjaxModalExtender, it works but problem is that when it appears then it

```
<asp:image ID="ImageLetterCopy"  style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%"   runat="server" />
```

doesn't hide anyway. I want to hide it, how can I do it ?

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField1" runat="server" />
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlMessageBox" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" TargetControlID="hdnField1"
                    PopupControlID="ImageLetterCopy">
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

i just want to hide it when some one clicks anywhere on page or any other simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this feature is not implemented. But you can try to attach a handler to a ModalPopup background element and simulate 'click' event for Cancel button (not tested):

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlMessageBox" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" TargetControlID="hdnField1" PopupControlID="ImageLetterCopy" BehaviorID="mdlMessageBoxBehavior">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<script type='text\javascript'>
var modalPopupBehavior = $find("mdlMessageBoxBehavior");
$(modalPopupBehavior._foregroundElement).click(function(){
    $(modalPopupBehavior._cancelControlID).trigger("click");
});
</script>
```